# Git BitBucket Clone With Different Username

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

I'm using Bitbucket, not Github. All the advice I find seems to be Github related. I installed git and I cloned a repository. The first time I did this, it gave me a popup and requested username and password which was great. Now, however, I want to change the username since that was just a test with my own account. Now I want it to be someone else's account who does not have the same permissions as me. But it never again asks for username and password. It just keeps cloning with the old username and password. It is a private project so it indeed requires authentication. I uninstalled and reinstalled Git and deleted all project information. It still seems to be using the old username and password when I clone. How do I change it??

Comment: What platform / git software are you using? I assume that you do not use the pure command line git (e.g. on linux) but some graphical client because you mentioned a pop-up.

Comment: I just downloaded "git" for windows which comes with a Git GUI, Git Bash, and Git Cmd. I'm just using Command Line commands to clone and the first time I did so, it indeed gave me a popup for credentials.

Comment: I guess it's part of the "Git Credential Manager" that came with the install

Comment: Ha, making me look up that little addon gave me the name to search better and actually find my answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Nice :) You can post the solution to your problem here as well such that other people can benefit from this as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Who knew it would be a Windows User Accounts thing? Sheesh...

1. Open "Credential Manager"
2. Click "Windows Credentials"
3. Delete the entry for Bit Bucket under Generic Credentials.

Comment: And, in fact, it's quite different on MacOS and Linux/Unix systems (all three use very different methods of storing keys and/or passwords temporarily or semi-permanently).